Removing Phase Offset from QPSK Received symbols with Phase offset and Noise using Phase locked loop
I'm designing a basic baseband transmitter and receiver that does QPSK modulation along with pulse shaping with Root raised cosine, some impairments are added to the transmitted signal to analyze the effect of the channel the impairments include Phase offset, Frequency offset, and AWGN noise.
Now, I want to use Phase locked loop to remove the effect of phase offset and frequency offset, but I'm stuck at it, what type of PLL will be used for this? Is there will be any decision-directed loop?
can someone guide me through this in detail?
Thank you in advance.

(Welcome to DSP.SE Muhammad - there are many answers already posted besides the one I linked, just search here on carrier recovery)   If you want the 15 hour answer with complete practical details including the PLL specifics and proper modeling for implementing carrier recovery and timing recovery, consider signing up for my "DSP for Software Radio" course starting next month: see https://dsprelated.com/courses !

Thanks Dan, I have one query about the loop filter gain how to model that ? I've implemented the phase detector using the answer you mentioned can you please help me with that ?

Hi Muhammad-- yes I can! That link above is the help you are looking for. The course videos are pre-recorded but I also do live weekly workshops and am available throughout the course for Q&A  (specific to the course content, which is what you are referring to). The best answer isn't a paragraph I can apply here and I've already gone through all the explanation there so refer you to that. it's starting soon and there is an early bird discount for registering now.  There's no better short cut to learning this if you want to be able to do this yourself, hope to see you there!
